# Gaussian Process with Monotonic Constraint

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process

I've been reading the paper [Gaussian Processes with Monotonicity Information](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/riihimaki10a/riihimaki10a.pdf), but I am confused about what Monotonicity Information to be included?

As the paper states, the authors model the joint GP which includes the observations and the derivative of the operating points. But they does not specifically point out what derivative to be included. I understand that the derivative need to be non-negative, do they just assign a random non-negative value to satisfy the monotonicity?

I also read a [survey paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.09319.pdf) which includes [Gaussian Processes with Monotonicity Information](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/riihimaki10a/riihimaki10a.pdf) in their Monotonicity Constraint section and saying "***Therefore, by including observations of y′ = 1 at the virtual points, the derivative is constrained to be positive.***", where y' is the derivative of the one-dimensional virtual points (aka operating points). Which makes me wonder if we just need to ***manually*** change the negative derivative to be a non-negative value.

***8th Nov 2022 Updates***: Maybe I can put some further thoughts based on the responses I got, now my question narrows down to - *do we just approximate the derivative of the operating points (which we just assume it to be non-negative but have no idea about what that is, however, we can solve it from the MLE) given the hyperparameters from the maximum likelihood estimate?*

Thanks for any reply!

Comment: This is a very specific question about one specific paper. Why not directly emailing the authors?

Comment: @KenGrimes Thanks for your reply! I actually emailed the author this afternoon, but haven't got any reply yet. My curiosity drives me to dig it out asap haha, so I just post this question.

Comment: They (approximately) try to condition on the derivative being *nonnegative*, not equal to any particular value: check out Eq 5 and the text immediately preceding and following.

Comment: @JohnMadden Hi John, I got the reply from the author and he said exactly as yours. Now from my point of view: We just assume the derivative of the operating points is non-negative, thus the monotonicity likelihood conditioning on the derivative is non-zero, but at the moment, we don't know what exactly that non-negative derivative right? Then, the author use EP algorithm to approximate the true posterior, which contains the non-Gaussian monotonicity likelihood. Then we use MLE to get the best fit hyperparameters, thus solve the derivatives (now we know what that is from MLE right?).

Comment: Yes that's right at a high level.

Comment: @JohnMadden Thanks for helping so far!